# Getting a black screen using the SWReveal Controller

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am having an issue with a black screen appearing on my app using the SWReveal Controller.    I had it going fine with a view controllers set up and behaving as expected, not sure what has changed to cause this.  The initial splash screen displays then straight to a black screen.  I have tried reseting the simulator and readding the intially controller but it seems to get upset when I reconnect the segues to the relevent views.

Any direction on this would be great. I don't want to redo the app; I’d rather figure out the root, in case this happens on another app further down the development life-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link.
http://samwize.com/2015/03/25/setting-up-swrevealviewcontroller/

You have to set front & rear view controllers.

Comment: Yes it was all working and not its stopped, frustrating :)  I could easily recreate the app but just want to get an understanding of the problems and how to solve them.  I will have a look over these answers.

Comment: Check your segues. Have u properly setted the identifier ?& the class to SWRevealViewController in storyboard ?